# Filtering by YEAR and MONTH when they're in different columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The data that I'm using contains DAY-MONTH-YEAR in separate columns and I want to create a filter using MONTH and YEAR combined. Here's an example:

```
transaction_id | customer | amount | day | month | year
---------------+----------+--------+-----+-------+-------
1                100         1000     01    05     2019
2                100          500     24    11     2018
3                100         2700     26    10     2018
4                205          800     19    11     2020
5                333         8000     05    05     2020
6                333          500     02    10     2019
7                333          200     19    12     2018
```

If I only want to return `transaction_id` that occur from January 2019 onwards, would this be done through something like a concat of MONTH + YEAR, and then create a new column with an alias? I tried doing something like this, but it kept returning just the year:

```
SELECT transaction_id, concat(MONTH, YEAR) AS FULLDATE
FROM sample_table
```

This returns FULLDATE values in the form of 201901 (for January 2019), but I'm wondering if this is indeed the correct approach here.

In addition, if so, how could I use this FULLDATE in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT transaction_id, concat(MONTH, YEAR) AS FULLDATE
FROM sample_table
WHERE FULLDATE >= 201901
```

How could I build this out into a subquery to be able to use the alias? Or should I try something like a HAVING clause? I tried both, but couldn't get it to run correctly. Maybe there's a better way altogether?

Comment: Are day and month text fields? Leading zeros would imply they are.

Comment: That's a good point, they're string values

Comment: Regardless, have to repeat calculation in WHERE clause. Alternative is to not concatenate and give each field its own parameter. Either way, most likely query will understand that parameter is numeric and automatically cast string to a numeric so comparison will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest math functions instead:

```
where year * 100 + month >= 201901
```

This assumes that `year` and `month` are numbers -- which seems reasonable.  If they are strings, use a string comparison:

```
where concat(year, month) >= '201901'
```

Note:  If columns are numbers, this will produce `20191` for January, which is not what you intend.

In SQL Azure, you can actually define this as a calculated column:

```
alter table t add yyyymm as (year * 100 + month);
```

(Or `concat()` if the columns are strings.)

Comment: That's really clever: where year * 100 + month >= 201901. I checked the YEAR/MONTH column types and they're strings. However, it looks like both of your methods work. I ran both instances with count(distinct transaction_id) and they're identical. Does that seem right to you or is there a better way I can try to validate?

Comment: @David . . . Both work.  Using `+` does an unnecessary implicit conversion to numbers.  If they are strings, use the string version.